# cURL not ON after changing settings in php.ini

Tags: php, curl, xampp, libcurl

I am trying to install **opencart** latest version. There is an error saying that `cURL` should be `ON` where as its in off state. I tried removing `;` from `extension=php_curl.dll` in `php.ini` file and that didn't work out.

Help me out with this issue. I am using **Xampp**.

Comment: Did you restart the xampp service?

Comment: restart apache web server

Answer (score 0):

Update these three files

```
C:\Program Files\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php4\php.ini
```

uncomment extension=php_curl.dll in each one

restart apache